# How do I get result by 'return' from NeDB in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bluebird, nedb, electron-vue

I am trying to get a data from NeDB in a method in a .vue file using electron-vue.
I know I can get that by putting that to a variable, but I want to get that by 'return' because I want to use the result in v-for.

I tried to use bluebird promisify and async/await but it's not work.

*datastore.js*

```
import Datastore from 'nedb'
import path from 'path'
import { remote } from 'electron'
export default new Datastore({
  autoload: true,
  filename: path.join(remote.app.getPath('userData'), '/data.db')
})
```

*main.js*

```
import db from './datastore'
Vue.prototype.$db = db
```

*test.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="member in memberName">
        {{ member.name }}（{{ member.relation }}）{{ member._id }}
        <ul>
          <li v-for="game in filterByName(member._id)">
            {{ game }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Promise from 'bluebird'
export default {
  // some data
  created: function () {
    this.dbFindAsync = Promise.promisify(thistest.$db.find)
  },
  methods: {
    filterByName: async function (id) {
      const docs = await this.dbFindAsync({ 'members.nameId': id }, { 'members': 1, _id: 0 })
      console.log(docs)
      return docs
    },
  // some other methods
  }
}
</script>
```

I got "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

I can get data from DB on created by this:

```
    this.$db.find({}, function (err, doc) {
      console.log(err)
      console.log(doc)
      this.list = doc || []
    }.bind(this))
```

Please help me....

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. Did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import on top of your script tag the `nedb` object.

something like this `const Datastore = require("nedb")`  and then initialize a new doc

```
 db = new Datastore({
    filename: "a_collection_of_data",
    autoload: true,
    timestampData: true,
  });
```

Then in your methods you have access to the `db` object.

Let's say you want to retrieve a collection of data in the getData method. It would look something like this

```
getData() {
    db.find({}, function(err, doc) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(doc)
        this.list = doc || []
    }.bind(this))
}
```